# How to change text of buttons created by using <button> tag after clicking on them for multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using multiple buttons which are created by button tag, I want to change text of each button separately when i am clicking on that button only.
I am trying to do with following code but it is not working at all..
how can i do it by using button tag...
Thanks...

Html code is

```
user1
<button class="toggle" href="/" onclick ="myFunction(this)">connect</button>
user2
<button class="toggle" href="/" onclick ="myFunction(this)">connect</button>
user3
<button class="toggle" href="/" onclick ="myFunction(this)">connect</button>
```

and js code is

```
<script>
function myFunction(obj) {
if (obj.value == "Connected")
    obj.value = "Connect";
else
    obj.value = "Connected";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change innerText instead of value and it is case sensitive

Buttons have value attributes but not href attributes

NOTE if the buttons are in a form, you need to use `type="button"` or add preventDefault to not submit the form

**Inline plain JS:**

```js
function myFunction(obj) {
  obj.innerText = obj.innerText == "Connect" ? "Connected" : "Connect";
}
```

```html
user1
<button class="toggle"  onclick="myFunction(this)">Connect</button> user2
<button class="toggle"  onclick="myFunction(this)">Connect</button> user3
<button class="toggle"  onclick="myFunction(this)">Connect</button>
```

**jQuery - with a link**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    var text = $(this).text(), link = $(this).data("url");
    $(this).text(text == "Connect" ? "Connected" : "Connect");
    $("#somediv").load(url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
user1
<button data-url="user1.html" class="toggle">Connect</button> user2
<button data-url="user2.html" class="toggle">Connect</button> user3
<button data-url="user3.html" class="toggle">Connect</button>
```

Comment: Actually i was not saying you did. I asked you, who did that

Comment: @mplungjan if i want to give link on button so how can i give it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `firstChild.nodeValue` instead of `value`

```js
function myFunction(obj) {
if (obj.firstChild.nodeValue == "Connected")
    obj.firstChild.nodeValue = "Connect";
else
    obj.firstChild.nodeValue = "Connected";
}
```

```html
user1
<button class="toggle" href="/" onclick ="myFunction(this)">connect</button>
user2
<button class="toggle" href="/" onclick ="myFunction(this)">connect</button>
user3
<button class="toggle" href="/" onclick ="myFunction(this)">connect</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you added the `jquery` tag, you could do this:

```
function myFunction(obj) {
  var o = $(obj);
  if (o.text() === "Connected")
      o.text("Connect");
  else
      o.text("Connected");
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j0z495et/

Answer (score 1):

try this you shoud use obj.innerText instead of  obj.innerTex

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(obj) {
if (obj.innerText == "Connected")
obj.innerText = "Connect";
else
obj.innerText = "Connected";
}
</script>
```